# Sperner family intersection with chains.

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-combinatorics

Consider a maximal sperner family $F$ of subsets of $X = \{ 1,2,3 \ldots n \}$. I need to prove that this family intersects with each chain of subsets exactly once.

Each chain is defined as :
$$\phi= A_0 \subset A_1 \ldots \subset A_n = X $$ where $A_i's$ are subsets of $X$.
The chain can not intersect at two points with $F$ from the definition of Sperner families. But how to that F intersects once with **every** chain.
Total number of chains are $n!$.

Comment: I reckon that the fact is incorrect: Consider the poset of subsets of $\{1,2,3,4\}$. The maximal antichain $\{\{1\},\{2,3,4\}\}$ has no element common with the maximal chain $\{2\} \subset \{2,3\} \subset \{2,3,1\} \subset \{2,3,1,4\}$

Comment: All subsets of same size form a maximal antichain. This has exactly one element common with any maximal chain.

Comment: A better question to ask here would be: Can we classify the maximal antichains such that they intersect with every maximal chain? I expect the answer to be: An antichain intersects with every maximal chain only if it contains all subsets of a particular size.

Comment: @talegari Nice remark. Your conjecture is true. In maximal antichain where subsets don't have same size it is possible to find subset A from antichain with max elements, and subset B not in antichain with |B|=|A| and |A\B|=1. Chain: ..., A\cap B, B, A\cup B, ... doesn't intersect antichain.